# kafka cannot communicate with zookeeper in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, minikube

my-k8s-zookeeper it seems is setting up successful
[image]

services seems it is up and running
[image]

my-k8s-kafka is had been restarts for 3 times, not idea what is the issue, the error keeps say it cannot connect to zookeeper service, services is running but kafka cannot communicate with zookeeper, may i know where has been wrongly setup.
[image]

[image]

> kafka-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-k8s-kafka
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
  matchLabels:
    component: my-kafka
template:
  metadata:
    labels:
      component: my-kafka
  spec:
    containers:
      - name: my-k8s-container-kafka
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9092
        env:
          - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
            value: "my-k8s-zookeeper-service:2181"
          - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
            value: "PLAINTEXT://my-k8s-kafka-service:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://my-k8s-kafka-service:9092"
          - name: KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
            value: "PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT"
          - name: KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME
            value: "PLAINTEXT"
          - name: KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR
            value: "1"
          - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
            value: "1"
          - name: KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS
            value: "1"
```

> kafka-deployment-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-k8s-kafka-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: my-k8s-kafka
  ports:
    - port: 9092
      targetPort: 9092
```

> zookeeper-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-k8s-zookeeper
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: my-zookeeper
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: my-zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-k8s-container-zookeeper
          image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
          env:
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT
              value: "2181"
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME
              value: "2000"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 1Gi
```

> zookeeper-deployment-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-k8s-zookeeper-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: my-k8s-zookeeper
  ports:
    - port: 2181
      targetPort: 2181
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to manage your own Deployment and Service? Use an operator that handles this for you https://strimzi.io

Comment: In any case, there's a page dedicated to this issue https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/

Comment: kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
this command when i execute, kubernetes shows me "No resources found in kube-system namespace."

Comment: You can use `minikube addons` subcommand to enable the DNS provider, I think? But mentioned here that if you use the docker driver DNS resolution doesn't work https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/

Comment: Thanks, now it is working, i am using this command minikube start --memory=4096, but it is becoming another error, which is Connection refused

Comment: You can follow the same troubleshooting guide above to run other commands. You have a network problem, not a Kafka problem (e.g. use ping and netcat to test connection)

Answer (score 0):

For a multi-container pod on minikube this is how the service and deployment yamls of zookeeper and kafka will look like.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: broker-conf
data:
  KAFKA_BROKER_ID: "1"
  ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 127.0.0.1:2181 
  BOOTSTRAP_SERVER: 127.0.0.1:9092 

  KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-service:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
  KAFKA_OPTS: -javaagent:/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/kafka/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.1.jar=9393:/confluent-7.0.1/etc/kafka/kafkaMetricConfig.yaml
  listeners: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
  advertised.listeners: PLAINTEXT://kafka-service:9092
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: client
      port: 2181
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    component: kafka-svc
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service 
spec:
  #type: ClusterIP
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: plaintext
      port: 9092
      protocol: TCP
    - name: plaintext-host
      port: 29092
      protocol: TCP
    - name: jmx-prom-port
      port: 9393
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31500
  selector: 
    component: kafka-svc
```

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: kafka-svc
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: kafka-svc 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: zookeeper
          image: localhost:5000/zookeeper 
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "125m"
            limits:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
          command: [ "/bin/sh","-c" ]
          args: ["/confluent-7.0.1/bin/zookeeper-server-start /confluent-7.0.1/etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties; sleep infinity"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
          env:
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT
              value: "2181"
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME
              value: "2000"
            - name: ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN
              value: yes

        - name: kafka
          image: localhost:5000/kafka
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "1Gi"
              cpu: "500m"
            limits:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: "1000m"
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: broker-conf
          command: [ "/bin/sh","-c"]
          args:
            - /confluent-7.0.1/bin/kafka-server-start /confluent-7.0.1/etc/kafka/server.properties --override zookeeper.connect=$(ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT);
            - /confluent-7.0.1/bin/kafka-topics --create --topic microTopic --bootstrap-server $(BOOTSTRAP_SERVER);
            - mkdir /prometheus/
            - sleep infinity;
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
              name: kafka-port
            - containerPort: 29092
              name: kafka-ad-port
            - containerPort: 9393
              name: jmx-export-port
```